# 403 Forbidden AJAX request in Magento 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, magento-2.0

I am using Magento 2 i want to send an AJAX request from my custom js.

Here is the code

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "app/code/Preview/Tag/Block/Baz/getTitle",
    data: {data: doc.output()},
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it returns 403 forbidden.

Please let me know what is causing the issue.

Controller code:

root_dir/app/code/Preview/Tag/Block/Baz.php

```
    <?php
namespace Preview\Tag\Block;

/**
* Baz block
*/
class Baz extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return "Foo Bar Baz";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

URL you are using is wrong , you need to learn about Magento2 Structure before you start code in Magento2.

what you are using is a Block not a Controller,

1st you need to define a route in file **etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="previewtag" frontName="previewtag">
            <module name="Preview_Tag" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

than after you need to define Controller file **Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Preview\Tag\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // your code here 
        echo "Foo Bar Baz";
    }
}
```

now you can use the URL as

`previewtag/index/index` or `previewtag`

both works same